# Trigger a new version of Page in SilverStripe

Tags: silverstripe

I am wondering if there is a way to create a new version on a `Page` object  in SilverStripe through code.

I am statically caching pages using the [staticpublisher](https://github.com/silverstripe-labs/silverstripe-staticpublisher) module. The issue I am facing is that when a DataObject is saved, it doesn't trigger a publish on the parent page, so the cache version is out of date. I have overcome this by running a `doPublish()` on the parent `Page` object. But that will obviously publish the page even if the publisher isn't ready for the new changes to go live.

**Here is what I have currently on my DataObject:**

```
function onAfterWrite() {
    parent::onAfterWrite();

    // Get the current page
    $page = Controller::curr()->currentPage();
    if($page) {
        // Publish the page
        $page->doPublish();
    }
}
```

Is there a way to create a new version of the page upon saving the `DataObject` and setting the `Page` to draft?

I have interrogated this [`Versioned` class](http://api.silverstripe.org/master/class-Versioned.html) but could not get anything to work from there.

Any ideas would help.

Comment: What do your Page to DO relations look like? I'm assuming the `onAfterWrite` is on the DO, so if there's a `has_one` back to a page would you publish `$this->YourRelationToPage()` rather than `Controller::curr()->currentPage()`?

Comment: I have used `Controller::curr()->currentPage()` as I have some deeply nested object realtionships and getting the page object for a DataObject 4 levels deep would be a little messy / tricky. The current `Controller::curr()->currentPage()` is returning the parent page no matter how deeply I am nested.

Comment: To test I just updated the `$page` variable to be the `Page` `has_one` relationship and the issue remains.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you've created a relationship between your SiteTree object and your DataObject (i.e. a hasOne, hasMany, or ManyMany). If that is the case, you should have a reverse relationship from the DO back to SiteTree (let's call it ParentPage).

You can trigger a draft save on your page using the DataObject's onAfterWrite() call.

```
class MyDataObject {
 //define a relationship back to the parent
 private static $belongs_to = array('ParentPage' => 'Page');

 //define this function on your DataObject
 public function onAfterWrite() {
  parent::onAfterWrite();

  //trigger a write (but not a publish) on your parent page
  $this->ParentPage()->write();
 }
}
```

Comment: That made sense to me too, but the write does not appear to be bumping the version up nor is it putting the page into draft mode...

Comment: According to http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-DataObject.html#_write you could try to set $forceWrite to true, e.g. `$this->ParentPage()->write(false, false, true);`

Comment: Try doing `$this->ParentPage()->writeToStage('Stage')`

Comment: Neither of those are working for me, definately sounds like they should though.

Comment: Doesn't the https://github.com/silverstripe-labs/silverstripe-staticpublisher/blob/master/docs/en/StaticPublisher.md#usage guide you to add the FilesystemPublisher extension to your DataObject Class and then add the  public function pagesAffectedByChanges in it. The main idea isn't to publish the parent page just invalidate the cached version of it.

Comment: Ah that wasn't event based thing. But I think you need to report that the url is required to be invalidated from that dataobject. Or if that doesn't work one way would be to delete the parent urls cached file > on the next generation that should be recreated as its missing. But id suggest first on trying adding the extension to the databOjects that need to tell the paths that they might be used. As a suggestion we have used the [staticpublishqueue](https://github.com/silverstripe-labs/silverstripe-staticpublishqueue) on couple of projects  and it has events that you can fire to cause updates.